# MySQL query to return all the text between the two words indicated (substring?)

Tags: mysql, sql, substring

I have some long text saved in one of the columns of my table.

And there is a part of the text I want to get from it...
For example, everything between 'words' IMPORTANTSTART and IMPORTANTEND...

How can I get it, if I don't know the exact length of that part?
I can't use SUBSTRING() as the number of characters is always different.

Is there any way to do that? I've tried to find some similar function that would allow me to do that, but couldn't find anything...

```
A lot of words here IMPORTANTSTART some data IMPORTANTEND more words

Even more words IMPORTANTSTART very important data IMPORTANTEND words
```

Maybe there is a way to remove everything  before IMPORTANTSTART and after IMPORTANTEND from the query output, while not changing this text in the database?

Answer (score 4):

Try with [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
SET @s := 'A lot of words here IMPORTANTSTART some data IMPORTANTEND more words';

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@s, 'IMPORTANTSTART', -1), 'IMPORTANTEND', 1)
```

**Output:**

```
some data
```

Comment: Is it possible to modify this for a use on a multiple rows given by a subquery?

Comment: Is it possible for the result to be:
IMPORTANTSTART some data IMPORTANTEND?

Comment: @inside83 Yes, this is possible

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if you wrote how

Comment: @inside83 `CONCAT('IMPORTANTSTART', SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@s, 'IMPORTANTSTART', -1), 'IMPORTANTEND', 1), 'IMPORTANTEND')`

Comment: Thanks @GiorgosBetsos it solve my request to extract number in picture url like text_12.jpg :  ```sql SELECT substring_index(substring_index(url, '_', -1), '.', 1)```

Answer (score 1):

I think this can work. As an example, I use the strings `abc` and `cba` as start and end delimiters, respectively.

```
select @string := 'text abc important cba more text'
     , @start_delim := 'abc'
     , @end_delim := 'cba'
     , @start_pos := instr(@string, @start_delim) + length(@start_delim)
     , @end_pos := instr(@string, @end_delim)
     , mid(@string, @start_pos, length(@string) - @end_pos - 1)
```

---

**Edit**

All you need to do is add your table to use this for all your data. Also, you can use a subquery to initialize the relevant variables, and "compact" expressions so you only get what you need:

```
select articles
     , mid(
         articles, 
         instr(articles, @start_delim) + length(@start_delim),
         length(articles) - instr(articles, @end_delim) - 1
       ) as result
from (select @start_delim := 'abc', @end_delim := 'cba') as init
   , myarchive
```

As you can see, all that was needed was replace `@string` with the column name you want to work with.

Comment: How can I modify this for a use on a multiple rows? Can I loop through multiple rows in the table instead of directly inserted line at `@string := ` somehow?
Just inserting a subquery - something like `(SELECT articles FROM myarchive)` - instead of `'text abc important cba more text'` gives me a "Subquery returns more than 1 row" error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [INSTR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) to calculate indexes of your start/end for `SUBSTRING`.